# root folder /opt/ is disappeared (By command mistake)

Tags: command-line

I Just want to move my desktop folder to `/opt/` folder.. but unfortunately I wrote the wrong command from root group.. command below

```
root@Lenovo:/home/hasan/Desktop# mv /opt/ DataGrip-2017.1
```

Now my `/opt/` folder disappeared...

What happened and what do I need to do to return this folder?

The output of `ls -l /home/hasan/Desktop/DataGrip-2017-1` is :

```
total 28 
drwxrwxr-x 2 hasan hasan 4096 এপ্রি 4 21:57 bin 
-rw-r--r-- 1 hasan hasan 15 মার্চ 21 15:52 build.txt 
drwxrwxr-x 2 hasan hasan 4096 এপ্রি 4 21:57 help 
-rw-r--r-- 1 hasan hasan 1900 মার্চ 21 15:52 Install-Linux-tar.txt 
drwxrwxr-x 4 hasan hasan 4096 এপ্রি 4 21:57 jre 
drwxrwxr-x 3 hasan hasan 4096 এপ্রি 4 21:57 lib 
drwxrwxr-x 2 hasan hasan 4096 এপ্রি 4 21:57 license
```

Comment: Could you include the results of  `ls -l  /home/hasan/Desktop/DataGrip-2017-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities when `mv`ing a directory:

1. `mv directory file` fails with the message `mv: cannot overwrite non-directory 'file' with directory 'directory'`
2. `mv directory1 directory2` moves `directory1` inside of `directory2`
3. `mv directory nothing-yet` renames `directory` as `nothing-yet`

Since `/opt` is gone, possibility 1 isn't the case. Since `opt` doesn't appear in the directory listing you present in the comment under your question, possibility 2 isn't the case. The only remaining possibility is possibility 3.

To fix it, rename it back to `/opt`:

```
mv /home/hasan/Desktop/DataGrip-2017.1 /opt
```

Comment: It looks like OP moved `/opt` into the `/home/hasan/Desktop/DataGrip-2017.1`-directory. What if `/opt` wasn't empty?

Comment: @mook765 in a comment under the question, the OP gives a listing of the contents of `DataGrip-2017.1`. It doesn't contain a directory called `opt`, which means that `opt` wasn't moved into anything. This means that `~hasan/Desktop/DataGrip-2017.1` didn't exist yet. What actually happened was that the `mv` command renamed `/opt` as `~hasan/Desktop/DataGrip-2017.1`.

Comment: Sorry, missed that comment. Important information should be added to the question, specially when it needs formatting. So your answer seems to be correct.